# Change to passive voice

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

Please explain how to change this interrogative sentence into passive voice.

> Is he the musician for the evening?

I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: How can a sentence whose verb phrase is not transitive but copular be passivised?

Comment: I don't know. This was asked in an exam. I couldn't find a way to change this setntence into passive voice, that's why I put it out. Anyway, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 7):

Is he the musician for the evening?

It's not possible to change the sentence into the passive as the verb be (is) is a linking verb.

You don't form passive structures with linking verbs like be, seem, become where the complement of the verb refers back to the subject. You need a transitive verb, which has an object, to form the passive. For example:

They requested me (object) to be the musician for the evening (active).

I was requested (by them) to be the musician for the evening (passive).

Answer (score 0):

> He is requested to be the musician for the evening.